# why app crashed in launch report of play store?

Tags: android

SO, my app works fine when used with android studio, though, it crashes according to play store in launch report.why is that happening ?
It keeps on crashing according to report of play store
How am I required to fix this issue[image: Image Shown]

In image there is issue of unable to start activity 
Pls help me 
Its my 1st app on play store and It is nice voice assisted app

Also
when I open apk file in android studio 
It shows  the following line in error,though following line is not shown in error in project itself 
error is of uri is not registered (settings languages & frameworks schemas and dtds)

[image: Image of Apk that was created by generating signed key, in android studio]

[image][image]

Your answers will be very helpful

If you want, I can share log that i got from play store

Comment: Have you checked the logcat to see what the error is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: It's unlikely, though not impossible, that we'll be able to answer this question for you, as you basically aren't giving *any* details about the crash.  Can you share some code that crashes?  A [mcve]?  Even just a complete traceback?  Take a look at [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/, if you follow the suggestions there you'll be much happier with the results you get on stack overflow.

Comment: yes I will share and add more info, i am editing, please wait

Comment: dbc, i  edited and provided pictures, pls help

Comment: a_local_nobody, no, brother, it did not. on opening apk file in android studio, error is of uri not registered

Comment: Carc, i am noobie, I dealt with errors of android studio and solved them while creating app,but Am not able to face error of play store, I downloaded log cat as provided by reports of play store,and being noob, it is difficult

Comment: you might be missing a proguard/R8 configuration.

Comment: martin, thanks for your reply, I am noob and I have spent months to make voice assisted app, I do not want to loose all of this, There is no error in android studio, Please, tell me about R8,

Comment: how to know if i have that or not, also does not having that can cause error of uri not registered as i mentioned in only apk file and i did check, i have this line    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: @VaibhavKumar - that helps somewhat, but might you please [edit] your question to include your code and exception details as **text** rather than as a screen shot?  Stack Overflow requests that you should include your code, error messages, exception details and textual data (JSON, XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).

Comment: Possibly relevant: [`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4512981/3744182).  The entire Logcat, as text, might help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will give you entire Text here

Comment: It was exceeding limit of words here, so I download that logcat from play store, uploaded to my drive, made it shareable and here is link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ElBZmw2jqEf1SCjz7V6IUkdVnFCACP_x

Comment: Maybe related then: [google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses not working after obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55781872).

Comment: I did some changes and now it worked on 12 devices but failed on 1 device android 4.3, error is still of compento like befir, can you please explain that if android studio made app without errors, then how on some device app crashes